# Uncaught ReferenceError: getChecked is not defined using Webpack Bundler

Tags: javascript, webpack, uncaught-reference-error

I am using the Webpack bundler to bundle my code, but I get an error saying my getChecked() function is not defined when I run my html page in a browser even though getChecked() *is* defined and included in the bundle. `Uncaught ReferenceError: getChecked is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):36:71)`

Here is how my project is organized: I have one file "getAPIToken.js" which gets an API token through a function called fetchToken(). I have another file "fetchSymptoms.js" which imports fetchToken() and uses it to get the token and display some data. "fetchSymptoms.js" defines the function getChecked(), which executes when a button is clicked. "fetchSymptoms.js" is the entry point to my webpack bundler.

I'm not sure how to make getChecked() be recognized in my browser. How can I make getChecked() be recognized by my browser? Do I need to make sure it's loaded first? I have been super stuck on this for the past two weeks, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The function getChecked() is defined in fetchSymptoms.js as follows:

```
 import { fetchToken } from './getAPIToken.js';
    

    fetchToken()
    .then(token => {
        fetchAdultMaleSymptoms(token);
        //fetchSymptoms(token);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error in fetchSymptoms ', error);
    });


function getChecked(){ //displays symptoms from checked checkboxes
    //alert("hello!");
    const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("symptom"); //items contains nodelist with the checked symptoms
    const array=[]; //create empty array

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){ //run through the nodelist
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked == true){
            if (!array.includes(checkboxes[i].value)){ //if the symptom is not already in array, then push
                array.push(checkboxes[i].value); //add checked items to array
            }
        }
    }

    const jsonArray = JSON.stringify(array); //converts to json string
    sessionStorage.setItem("checked", jsonArray); //will disappear when browser window closed, can use localStorage
}
```

So the function is defined, and then eventually bundled since fetchSymptoms.js is the entry point. Here is how I use getChecked() in index.html. When run in my browser, index.html gives me errors saying uncaught getChecked() not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Prognosis Pal</title>
   
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/fetchSymptoms.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/displayCategories.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/js/diagnosisSymptoms.js"></script> -->
    
</head>

<body>
    <a href="/you"><button class="you-button">You</button></a>

    <h1>PrognosisPal</h1>

    <div>Select all symptoms that apply</div>

    <div class="symptoms-container">
        <form action="#" id="symptomForm">  
            <div id="ul-container"></div>
            <!-- Symptoms used come from API -->
        
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- getChecked() gets the values that the user selects for symptom checkboxes-->
    <a href="/diagnosis"><button type="submit" onclick="getChecked()">Diagnosis Me!</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, here is my webpack.config file:

```
const path = require('path');
//require('dotenv').config({ path: './functions/.env' }); 
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');


module.exports = {
  entry: './public/js/fetchSymptoms.js', //entry point of your application ./public/js/getAPIToken.js
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js', //output bundle filename, where result is going to go
    path: path.resolve('public'), //output directory
  },
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Match JavaScript files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Exclude node_modules
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Use Babel to transpile JavaScript
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] // Use the preset for modern JavaScript
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      'crypto-js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/crypto-js'),
    },
  },
};
```

I'm not sure how to make getChecked() be recognized in my browser. Do I need some sort of html plugin included in my webpack.config file? I have been super stuck on this for the past two weeks, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define global variable with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out-- because I had one entry point for my bundle, I included the script bundle.js in index.html and next.html, which meant when I moved from index.html to next.html, the entire bundle script executed again, which meant my code ran twice.

To solve this issue, I created two entry points, one per each HTML file, and included one script for index.html and a different script for next.html. Here's my new entry point in my webpack config file:

```
  entry: {
    file1: ['./public/js/fetchSymptoms.js'],
    file2: ['./public/js/diagnosisSymptoms'],
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue is similar to this, can check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781579/basic-webpack-not-working-for-button-click-function-uncaught-reference-error)

> When you run the file over webpack, webpack will try not to litter the global scope and so the function will not be made available
> globally by default.
>
> If you want the function to be accessible outside the scope of he JS
> file, you should put it in the global scope.

```
function uclicked() {
  // do something
}
window.uclicked = uclicked;
```

> Or just:

```
window.uclicked = function() {
  // do something
}
```